# Bypassing Comment by XSS

Tags: xss

I'm learning Web Security currently, and my tutor left this practice for us. Is there any solution to bypass this js statements and as a result, for example, to display alert(1)? Thanks!

```
input = input.replace(/-->/g, '')
return '<!-- ' + input + ' -->'
```

I know how to do it without the replacement. But I'm stuck on the replacement. I was trying to use SVG but it didn't work either.

UPDATE

I find it's possible to use --!> and it worked.

Comment: Consider adding the solution as an answer instead of editing the question. This way, the system knows the question is solved.